# Cálculo entre Linhas e Colunas Diferentes SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso de uma solução ou função para realizar o seguinte cálculo

```
(Backlog(dia anterior) + Abertos(dia atual)) - fechados(dia atual) = backlog(dia atual)
```

Segue imagem da tabela abaixo. Nunca me deparei com esta situação de ter que calcular valores entre linhas de colunas diferentes. Li algo sobre Lead e Leg mas não consegui aplicar a solução ao que preciso, alguém consegue dar uma luz?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `lead` faria exatamente o que precisa, pode mostrar o que já tentou e pq não deu certo?

Comment: select [data criação], [abertos], [fechados],
(LEAD([backlog],1, null) OVER (ORDER BY [Data Criação]) + [abertos])  - [fechados] as [backlog] 
from [santander - abertos - teste]

Answer (score 0):

Não fiz da maneira mais esperta do mundo, inclusive pode ter um desempenho ruim para grandes cargas de dados. Estou levando em consideração que cada linha esteja numerada unicamente de maneira crescente (não que isso seja um grande problema, dá para contornar isso).

No caso, cada linha contém 3 informações cruas:

1. um identificador da linha (no caso que você exibiu, é uma data; vou transformar em `id`)
2. a quantidade de `Aberto`
3. a quantidade de `Fechado`

Assim, cada linha contém um atributo derivado dela, o "saldo". No caso, saldo é `aberto - fechado`. Posso fazer o seguinte mapeamente:

```sql
with _saldo as (
  select
    id,
    aberto - fechado as saldo
  from linhas
)
select * from _saldo
```

Note que isso me trará apenas o quanto cada dia "movimentou". Precisamos, entretanto, acumular esses movimentos para saber o quanto tem no todo até o momento:

```sql
with _saldo as (
  select
    id,
    aberto - fechado as saldo
  from linhas
), burndown as (
  select
    id,
    (select sum(s2.saldo) from s2 where s2.id <= s.id) as backlog
)
select * from burndown
```

Para deixar cada linha tendo o seu identificador único, podemos usar o `ROW_NUMBER`. O `ROW_NUMBER` irá gerar um  número de linha para cada linha, e para ele poder saber como enumerar as linhas, precisamos dizer o que ele precisa levar em consideração para "ordenar" os registros e enumerá-los. No caso, estou chamando a coluna genericamente de "dia" (já que mencioná-la assim é mais trivial no SQL do que "Data criação"). No caso, note que a CTE `linhas` pode ser substituída sem nenhum problema pela tabela que contenha os dados reais:

```sql
with linhas as (
    select '2018-01-01' as dia, 10 as aberto, 9 as fechado
    union all
    select '2018-01-02' as dia, 7 as aberto, 3 as fechado
    union all
    select '2018-01-03' as dia, 0 as aberto, 5 as fechado
), _v as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dia) as id, dia, aberto, fechado from linhas
), saldo as (
    select dia, id, aberto - fechado as saldo
    from _v
), burndown as (
    select
        dia,
        s.id,
        (select sum(s2.saldo) from saldo s2 where s2.id <= s.id) as acumulado
    from saldo s
)
select dia, acumulado from burndown
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mano
Consegui resolver o problema utilizando outra solução:
segue:
DECLARE @@Dia_Atual DATETIME, @@dia_anterior DATETIME
SET @@Dia_Atual = 'Aug  2 2019 12:00AM'
SET @@dia_anterior =  @@dia_atual - 1

WHILE @@Dia_Atual < GETDATE()
BEGIN
UPDATE [SANTANDER - ABERTOS - 1]
SET [BACKLOG] = (SELECT [SALDO] FROM [SANTANDER - ABERTOS - 1] WHERE [DATA CRIAÇÃO] = @@Dia_Atual) +
(SELECT [BACKLOG] FROM [SANTANDER - ABERTOS - 1] WHERE [DATA CRIAÇÃO] = @@dia_anterior)
WHERE [DATA CRIAÇÃO] = @@Dia_Atual
SET @@Dia_Atual = @@Dia_Atual + 1
SET @@dia_anterior = @@Dia_Atual -1